# Some problems about DI in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am practicing DI and tried to be modular in angular.js.I had searched some tutorial and try to recode it.

What I plan at first is as following(I might have the wrong concepts,please help to point out):

1. An ng-app:myapp;

   An module "finance2" with an factory service:"currencyConverter";

   ```
   angular.module('finance2', []).factory('currencyConverter', function() {
   ```

   An module "ctrl1" with an controller:InvoiceController. Then I inject the service module into it

   ```
   angular.module('ctrl1',['finance2']).controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter', '$scope',function(currencyConverter,$scope) {
   ```
2. Then I inject the the controller module to the app

   ```
    var app = angular.module("switchableGrid",['ctrl1']);
   ```

Here is the complete code,jsfiddle.net/c7fF3/1/,

But nothing happend, could some one give me an hint?Many thanks.

Comment: I am pretty certain that you cannot inject one module into another. You can inject directives, factories, services, etc. You might want to read AngularJS' [Dependancy Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) guide.

Comment: @Adam This is not injecting, it's declaring dependencies to another module, and this is definitely possible in angular

Comment: Along with the suggestions @Chandermani has provided, you have specified a module for `ng-app` that does not exist. Here is a modified version of your JSFiddle I quickly edited: http://jsfiddle.net/c7fF3/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your fiddle i changed the **Framework and extensions** section second dropdown to "no-wrap in body" and i see not exception being logged.

Also if you are using *controller as* syntax, you should use

`this.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;`

instead of

`$scope.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;`

Comment: how can you not see an exception when angular is trying to bootstrap module that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

you are using `ng-app="myapp"` but your app is actually a module called `switchableGrid`

either change markup to

```
<body ng-app="switchableGrid">
```

or change the script to

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ctrl1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            .when('/xxx', { templateUrl: 'app/xxx.html', controller: 'xxxCtrl' })

    }])

    .factory(
        'currencyConverter',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource(URL);
        })


    .controller('xxxCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$route', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route) {      
$scope.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;
    }])
```